# Can I play Pokemon Go in a country that I am visiting?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm from the United States and I'll be visiting Canada soon. Since Pokémon GO is not out for Canada yet, would I still be able to play and catch Pokémon in Canada seeing as my phone/game/account all originate from the United States?

For that matter, will I be able to play Pokémon GO in Canada once it is released in Canada? Or am I restricted to playing in the United States only?

Comment: Caution to your data consumption !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only play Pokemon GO if *the server allows you to play from the country you are visiting*, as evidenced by [this incident](http://www.nme.com/news/various-artists/94966) involving an Australian expat who visited Singapore and wasn't able to play Pokemon GO. They seem to allow/block based on IP address geolocation, since there is an article with [instructions to use VPN to workaround the block](http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/feature-how-get-pok-mon-go-ios-or-android-without-rooting-or-using-dodgy-apks).

Since there had been reports about people in Europe being able to play the game before the game is officially supported, the server evidently allows many countries beyond countries officially supported.

You can check the [list of supported countries on releases.com](http://www.releases.com/availability/pokemon-go), or follow the news and social media to see whether the game is supported in a particular country.

Comment: You can add South Korea on that NO! list unfortunately :(

Comment: Apparently it works in Poland, specifically in [Auschwitz.](http://nymag.com/selectall/2016/07/yes-you-can-catch-pokemon-at-auschwitz.html)

Comment: You can add The Netherlands.

Comment: @Kiwi to which list? The one where it works or doesn't work?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid working list, sorry haha

Comment: Since when it is available for germany? I was yesterday trying to find a release date for germany when I noted not finding it in the appstore and didn't even find that. sooo... sure?

Comment: @Zaibis The apk is available, so you have to download it to play it. Not from the store.

Comment: @zaibis It is officially available since this morning in Germany.

Comment: Apparently it works in Philippines

Comment: @offbyoni: yeah jsut to see my device is not compatible -.- *sigh*

Comment: Contrary to your message Pokemon GO is being played even in Singapore from day one. Here is one of the Singaporean Pokemon GO players' FB page: https://www.facebook.com/groups/PokemonGoSG/

Comment: @Montag451: I guess that they were able to play because they used VPN to work around the block, or maybe the server unblock access (unannounced) from Singapore IP. In my country, after the server overload and they had to block access, they did unblock access once for a few hour before blocking it again.

Answer (score 14):

The game field is global. You can play it all over the world. This is both evidential from Ingress and the current Pokemon GO user base who play it globally at the moment with downloaded APKs.

Comment: Well then. Someone with a high level Pokemon Go account and a satellite internet hookup needs to climb Mt. Everest and let us know what Pokemon live up there.

Comment: @Ellesedil Articuno.

Comment: @Ellesedil. Would be a really nice touch if we could find Red at the top of [Mt. Fuji](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mt._Silver).

Comment: @Ellesedil the nearest Ingress portal seems to be nearly 100km away in Bhimeshwar, so Pokemon are probably nonexistent.

Comment: @Virusbomb shhh, you're spoiling the *mystic*

Comment: @Ellesedil Run it in an Android emulator and set the GPS location to Mt. Everest :-)

Comment: @wb9688 I think that's against the terms of service.

Comment: @Virusbomb I doubt Articuno would live there. In canon lore, he lives deep inside a cave in an island somewhere on Route 20. based on the map, that would be somewhere between Oshima Island and Miura

Comment: @Nzall can you quote that part of the terms of service?

Comment: @wb9688 I'm not sure since the Pokémon Go terms currently give a 404, but the Ingress terms explicitly state that you will not "submit fake, falsified, misleading, or inappropriate data submissions, edits, or removals.". I'd say emulating your GPS location would be fake data submission. Since the Ingress terms contain this stipulation, it's likely the Pokémon Go terms would have a similar one.

Answer (score 1):

Japan is in the testing phase so you can walk around all you want but you aren't gonna get any Pokemons popping up. I walked all ard Shinjuku and Hakone with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely you can play Pokemon Go in Canada too. Because this is a Global Game. You can play it everywhere in the world once you have it.

Comment: Can you play it in a country where the app is not available, like China or Japan?

Comment: @blaszard you can play, but no pokemon will show up.